# Typescript Intersection with shared properties

Tags: typescript, types, intersection, typescript-generics

I'm trying to understand Typescript interfaces better.

I've defined the following interfaces:

```
interface Bob<T> { 
  x : number; 
  y : string;
  z? : T;
}

interface Jennie<T> { 
  x : number; 
  y : number;
  q : number;
  z? : T;
}
```

Next I've created this variable:

```
let myIntersection : Bob<string> & Jennie<number> = {
  x: 20, y: 'hi', q: 30, z: 20
}
    
console.log(myIntersection);
```

This throws an error:

```
  solution.ts:3:3
3   y : string;
    ~
The expected type comes from property 'y' which is declared here on type 'Bob<string> & Jennie<number>'solution.ts:49:24 - error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

I understand that in principle the idea is that the `&` will combine the properties of both `Bob` and `Jennie` and create a new type so if `Bob` has properties `x`, `y` and `Jennie` has properties `a`, `b` - `Bob & Jennie` will have `x`,`y`,`a`,`b` - but how does this work in more complex situations like the one above where we have:

1. the same property defined in both `Bob` and `Jennie` but with different types (`y`)
2. the optional `z` property which is `string` in `Bob` and `number` in `Jennie`

Are there some general rules which are followed in this case or is my code invalid?

Comment: Intersection creates a type whose properties are assignable to all types of the intersection. There are zero objects that can be assigned to both Bob and Jennie, since they have conflicting types for the `y` property. `Bob & Jennie` is `never`. The same goes for generic and optional types.

Comment: So in this case, I wouldn’t be able to create an intersection of Bob and Jennie? Or would I be able to create one, but the `y` property would have type `never`?

Comment: I mean you can create it, but it would be unusable since the `y` property would be type `never`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglUF4oG8BQ8BmB7LAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcqAvqqqJFAEKIrpTZ5TkCuAWwBGEYrQZNw0AMIc4AMja0pLAJocZAbQDkPHQF1qUAPQm+EAG5jGAYyzkiUW-jlI0mHPgCMp8wBVpKB0BETEdKFICPixgKABDAgJSSnJ44QAbaGAsKGZoEKtwgDoACgAmAGZy8oBKekYgA